# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find RoutePredicateFactory with name header

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am learning Spring Boot Microservices from https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-boot-microservices-and-spring-cloud/learn/lecture/23952722#notes and using Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring Boot v2.5.2.

Error

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'eurekaAutoServiceRegistration'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find RoutePredicateFactory with name header
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.example.ApiGatewayApplication.main(ApiGatewayApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find RoutePredicateFactory with name header
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.lookup(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:203) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.combinePredicates(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.convertToRoute(RouteDefinitionRouteLocator.java:116) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:106) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:488) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:421) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.drain(FluxMergeSequential.java:432) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.innerComplete(FluxMergeSequential.java:328) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialInner.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:552) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onNext(FluxMergeSequential.java:237) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:270) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMergeSequential$MergeSequentialMain.onSubscribe(FluxMergeSequential.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:164) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:86) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalFluxOperator.subscribe(InternalFluxOperator.java:62) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefer.subscribe(FluxDefer.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8235) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2518) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.lambda$onApplicationEvent$0(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.ifAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2035) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter.onApplicationEvent(WeightCalculatorWebFilter.java:133) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.reset(RouteRefreshListener.java:73) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteRefreshListener.onApplicationEvent(RouteRefreshListener.java:54) ~[spring-cloud-gateway-server-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:378) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:85) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.3.jar:3.0.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2519) ~[reactor-core-3.4.7.jar:3.4.7]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8082
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka


spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true


spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=users-status-check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://users-ws
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/spring-ws/users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Method=GET
# Needed for JWT
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie

# If request is coming /spring-ws/users/status/check, then Spring cloud API gateway will route it to /users/status/check
#spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/spring-ws/users/status/check, /users/status/check
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[1]=RewritePath=/spring-ws/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiGateway</name>
    <description>Photo App Eureka Discovery Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependenc
```

yManagement>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by using, it was lower case header which will not work.

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[2]=Header=Authorization, Bearer (.*)
```